# fscanf() shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: c, file, graph, scanf, fopen

I'm trying to read a .txt file and convert it to a graph struct that i've previously implemented and tested succesfully. I'm using fscanf function so it turns to be easier to read specific values. Here's the code:

```
int readGraph(char* fileName, Graph* graph) {
FILE* filePointer;
int nodes, edges;

filePointer = fopen(fileName, "r");
if(!filePointer) {
    fprintf(stderr, "[READ-GRAPH] Unable to open file");
    return(0);
}

if(fscanf(filePointer, "%d %d", &nodes, &edges) != 2)
    return (0);
initialize(graph, nodes);

int fromNode, toNode;
Weight weight;
while((fscanf(filePointer, "%d %d %f", &fromNode, &toNode, &weight)) != EOF) {
    printf("fromNode value %d toNode value %d weight value %f\n", fromNode, toNode, weight);
    addEdge(graph, fromNode, toNode, weight);
}

fclose(filePointer);
return (1);}

int main() {

    Graph graph;
    readGraph((char*) filename, &graph);
    print(&graph);
}
```

Each line contains two nodes values and a float weight (except the first line, which contains the number of nodes and edges desired). The problem is that, when reading the 'grafo1.txt', I get garbage value at somepoint. Also, using the file 'grafo.txt' the reading is not even completed (it prints until line 6 and then the program crashes).

```
grafo.txt:
4 7
0 3 6.3
2 1 5.0
2 0 9
1 3 1.7
0 1 9
3 1 5.6
0 2 7.2

grafo1.txt
5 4
1 3 5.3
3 2 2
1 2 7.8
4 3 6

grafo1.txt output
fromNode value 1 toNode value 3 weight value 5.300000
fromNode value 3 toNode value 2 weight value 2.000000
fromNode value 1 toNode value 2 weight value 7.800000
fromNode value 4 toNode value 3 weight value 6.000000
[PRINT] Node 0
Connections:
[PRINT] Node 1
Connections: 2 (weight 7.800000), 3 (weight 5.300000),
[PRINT] Node 2
Connections:
[PRINT] Node 3
Connections: 2 (weight -463590750420992.000000), <- Garbage value. Why?
[PRINT] Node 4
Connections: 3 (weight 6.000000),

grafo.txt output
fromNode value 0 toNode value 3 weight value 6.300000
fromNode value 2 toNode value 1 weight value 5.000000
fromNode value 2 toNode value 0 weight value 9.000000
fromNode value 1 toNode value 3 weight value 1.700000
<- it crashes after this blank line
```

I really don't get why two .txt equally formatted are giving different outputs and also: why just one of them is able to almost succesfully create a graph? (almost because a garbage value is registered for some reason at somepoint). Any help is appreciated, i'm trying to learn everything i can about C.

Comment: On main function, 'filename' equals exactly "grafo.txt" or "grafo1.txt", it's just a placeholder.

Comment: Suspecting there is an extra new line in grafo.txt, causing the crash?

Comment: I've just checked but there isn't an extra new line

Comment: Try running the code line by line (debug). The crash may not be due to scanf, but some exception not handled in addEdge

Comment: I appreciate your help, Jayr. It's exactly what you told me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Jayr pointed out, the problem isn't related to readGraph function. Thank you Jayr.